# How do I know if my RJ45 socket is compatible with CAT5e cables?

Tags: ethernet, cable

I have three, around 16-year-old [RJ45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ45S) wall sockets in my house, and they were not used in more than a decade (I used Wi-Fi instead). I checked the cables in the wall and they are [Cat 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) type, which needs replacement. The problem is, I don't know if the wall socket itself is capable of [Cat 5e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) speeds. I could not find any printing on them which would tell the exact type of the sockets, just the make "Legrand".

Comment: Which "Cat5e" speeds are you planning on using – 1Gbps? 2.5Gbps?

Comment: The difference between cable speeds really is in the cable itself. If the cable behind the RJ45 socket are CAT5 (note CAT5 is very old, more than 16 years old), then it will work. But lets say that it would be CAT4, you can still connect a CAT6 cable over it, it will just not reach CAT6 speeds. The difference between the different category cables is how they were build and how they were shielded. Different kind of twisting and different connector. CAT5 and CAT5e and probably CAT4 and 3 all use the same connector. Its CAT6 and up where the cable itself got shielding.

Comment: Just make sure that the cable going into the wall connector has all 8 cables connected, otherwise you'll only get 100mbit speeds. aka CAT3.

Comment: "CAT5 type, which needs replacement" citation needed.

Comment: I would expect corrosion after a decade.

Comment: @Nelson I put in some CAT5 in the late '90s that still works fine.

Comment: +100yo phone jacks still work just fine. Corrosion on copper from moisture in the air quickly forms a patina and then stops. That layer is easily scrapped off every time you insert a plug. If it isn't, use a tiny wire brush. Unless your new jacks are made out of solid gold or silver, there's zero difference.

Answer (score 21):

There's nothing wrong with Cat 5 for domestic use - *especially if it's already there*.
It runs [1000BASE-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) (Gigabit Ethernet) if it's wired properly.

The first thing to do is see if they work… or whether they were wired for phones not Ethernet. If it doesn't work, or runs very slowly ([100BASE-TX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet) will show a yellow rather than green light on most Ethernet computer ports) then if you can pull one out of the wall, check they are wired like this -

[image]

The **B** specification is more popular, but either will work so long as all are the same.

If unused for a long time, they may have built up a patina on the connectors, so a can of electrical contact cleaner spray* would be cheaper & easier than a rewire.
BTW, 16 years isn't beyond life-expectancy for this. My own structure was first cabled 22 years ago, and with the occasional squirt of cleaner, is still good to this day.

*As noted in comments, this is not the same as a lubricating oil spray, such as [WD-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD-40), although they do also make a contact cleaner, with grey/silver/green highlighting, as opposed to their lubricant with the distinctive blue/yellow theme.

[image]

There are many types, but this one is easy to pick up at a local DIY store.

Comment: While T-568A & T-568B are 2 standards, there are many other combination that would be acceptable. What matters is that differential pairs are on a twisted pair. If you do have a different wiring to the ones above, just make sure that you have the "same color pairs". That is make sure that if where T-568A has green, you have orange, then where T-568A has green-white, you should have orange-white.

Answer (score 8):

RJ45 jacks and plugs are physically compatible with CAT 4, 5, 5e and 6 cabling.

Jacks can age, and plugs can age. It is possible to clean the contacts with contact cleaner but I prefer replacement in most cases. Better plastics and dielectric insulation.

Since you have 3 jacks, I suggest replacing them with new RJ45 sockets to be sure.

If you are mechanically adept, you can do it yourself. Otherwise get a local networking shop to install the new sockets.

New sockets are just renewal, not a compatibility issue.

Comment: This would be the correct answer to your question. 
For more details, I would refer you to this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/80014/is-there-a-difference-between-rj-45-plugs-for-cat-5e-and-cat-6

Comment: I would point one more difference, which is not related to Cat5 or 6: you can have sockets that support shielding, or not. Shielded ones will look metallic.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but...

Four [Cat 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable) wall sockets cost as little as US$15 ([example product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08TZZRPCF)). That's less than one month of high-speed Internet connection, so if you replace the cables it's just not worth to risk having old sockets which might work today but break tomorrow. Even just testing the old sockets will cost more than replacing them.

On a side note, consider putting in Cat 6 cables, depending on the cost of material vs. cost of work. It can give you 10 Gbit/s speed which is useful if you ever want to run a [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage).

Comment: On the other hand, badly fitted CAT 6  might well be worse than the current CAT 5. And while faceplates might be cheap, running new cable might not be.

Answer (score 1):

Older connectors will usually work just fine with the newer wiring, and you'll typically get full speeds even if they aren't rated for the full capability of the newer wire. If you don't, it's likely because you were already pushing the limits of the what the cabling could support, and that typically involves much longer runs than you find in a home.

Nevertheless, if you replace the wiring, I would replace the connectors at the same time. They only [cost about $1 each](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L8C3F6C) if ordered in bulk, you'll have to re-punch anyway, and it seems such a waste to have all this nice new wiring with these older/under-rated connectors.

---

As for needing to replace Cat5 with newer wire: I'll buck the trend and say it is *probably* a good idea, for a couple reasons. (Note: I would *not* worry about replacing 5e just yet).

One, fire code in many areas has changed over the last few decades, and depending on how/where the cables are run you may want to get plenum-rated wiring that likely wasn't a viable option when the cat5 was produced. Two, I'm seeing more and more 2.5G-capable equipment, and I expect this trend to accelerate. In another 5 to 10 years, 2.5G (or even 10G) will be the default, and cat5 is just not rated for it. It may still work, but cat6 will do up to 10G (and maybe even 40G). So if you're in the walls anyway and have an eye towards future-proofing your deployment, it's a good idea to update.

The caveat is copper-clad aluminum. This is a relatively new way to make cable using aluminum for the core of the wire with just a thin copper plating for the actual conductor. CCA wiring is good for short runs when PoE is not involved, but anything over about 60ft or that needs PoE, and I want solid copper. The cat 5 structural wiring in a home is likely full copper, because CCA wasn't common back then, and I'd view replacing it with CCA cat 6 as a step backwards.

Now also keep in mind full-copper plenum-rated cat6 generally costs north of $200 per 1000ft box, and that may also factor into a decision on whether to upgrade.

Comment: Hmm... pricing is good right now, and it's actually just LESS than $200 at the moment https://www.amazon.com/Plenum-Copper-1000ft-Ethernet-Network/dp/B0051DZTGQ/

Comment: If you're going into the walls, run a pair of cables everywhere you'd plan to run just one. Even if only one of the pair is connected at both ends. You'll thank me when someone nails into your cable by accident

Answer (score 0):

Like [John answered](https://superuser.com/questions/1814236/how-do-i-know-if-my-rj45-socket-is-compatible-with-cat5e-cables/1814238#1814238), and as it's been said in the comments, your socket doesn't matter much.

Now, as others said, you may not want to replace your cable. Like I commented on some other answers, if the wiring doesn't match TIA-568A/B, don't panic, it may still be fine. Check that each differential pair is on a twisted pair.

What you should do next is test your cable, I'd recommend using computers (for instance with [Iperf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf)), as testing equipment for that matter would be expensive (I mean, testing the speed).

Your Cat 5 cable might be as good as a Cat 6.

[Cat 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) is a specification that, for instance, guarantees that your cable will work with 1 Gbit/s Ethernet (within certain distances). It absolutely does not mean your cable will *not* work with other speeds.
While it may not be very likely, it's still entirely possible that your Cat 5 cable will do 2.5 Gbit/s, maybe 10 Gbit/s even. It partly depends on the cable length, and it also depends on a variety of other factors. Having had a quick look at Cat 5 and Cat 5, I can see for instance that a "big difference" is the [characteristic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_impedance) of a Cat 5 cable is 100 ohm +/- 15 ohm at 0-100 MHz. A Cat 6 cable is the same, on 0-250 MHz.

There's nothing to say that your Cat 5 cable does not have 100 ohm +/- on the whole 0-250 MHz. It's just not guaranteed when you buy it. Standards set "minimum requirements"; then don't forbid from surpassing them.

Answer (score 0):

Others have noted that the connectors and cabling are physically compatible and will function with the latest equipment.

An easy way to see if their performance is adequate is to connect via them to the Internet and run an Internet speed test, such as the widely used [Ookla SPEEDTEST](https://www.speedtest.net/).  Do this from a Internet main router outlet, via the cable of choice and if desired via other cables for comparison.

---

For interest - just after midnight on a Sunday morning, when the gamers will be in full cry, I get this result in [Auckland, NZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland). It is rather less than I thought I was paying for. I must check again at a quieter time.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"top connect via them"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: Verizon just upgraded my fiber connection because it was very old. No charge. They also then bumped the speed from 50 Mbps to 500 Mbps, also at no charge - I think the maximum even available with the old equipment was 100 Mbps. I did a test before - 59 Mbps. I did a test after - 94 Mbps - same as yours. In the process of figuring out some other problems (fortunately resolved by Verizon remotely), I found that I am only getting a 100 Mbps connection on the port - i.e., the problem is in the cabling. All 8 wires straight through, so my hunch is substandard wiring from around 17 years ago. But as

Comment: I told the installer setting up the new equipment **I just don't need more than 100 Mbps so it just doesn't matter**. Seriously. For a typical family, how much bandwidth does anyone actually **need**? I rarely have more than 5 people in the house. Usually only 3. Videos/Zoom/etc. x 3 = perhaps 20 - 30 Mbps. Occasional huge downloads? Yes. But as often limited by source as by destination. This world has gone crazy about bandwidth. I remember the good old days of 300 bps acoustic couplers...

Comment: @PeterMortensen  typo. corrected. Thanks. to connect <-- top connect. || PS when/if editing my posts spelling and obvious typos are fair game - leaving my pecadillos alone would be appreciated. (I make enough uncaught typos to keep any editor happy :-) ).